How to export a Random Forest Model from R into some function in a DLL file?
I developed a Random Forest Model in R, but need to export it somehow outside of R Studio and use it in a "decision engine" that is completely separate from R studio.
Can anyone advice me how to export such a Random Forest model into a function saved in a DLL file?
Alternatively, suggest any other idea, that would enable me to use the model outside of R Studio...
Imagine you have a "fraud model" that classifies, but you need to deploy such a model in a transaction payment system. How?
I did not get anywhere.

r-studio is an ide, r is an interpreter. r code is executed by r interpreter

for inference, maybe take a look of plumber https://www.rplumber.io/

rplumber.io  is about API. What I mean is different. What if I want to use my random forest in a live decision engine programmed in C++ or C# somewhere in a Bank?

use api is the simplest between languages.
or you can use xgboost which have c++ api

or you just implement your model in c++ or c#.
